# .tpl If statement in Class=""

Tags: php, html, smarty

```
<a class="{if $menu eq 1}current{/if}"
<a class="{if $menu eq 2}current{/if}"
<a class="{if $menu eq 3}current{/if}"
```

How does the $menu eq 1 work? Where can i find the "function"?

Trying to make the menu "Highlight" If it's selected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you're using a template engine. In that case, it'd be nice to know which.

Comment: Looks like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if). `eq` is just an alternative way of writing `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eq is equal to logical (==) operator of PHP, it is a smarty template engine equivalent of PHP

for eg.

```
<?php
if($menu == 1) {
?>
class="current"
<?php
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "Smarty" oh and $menu is a variable, where is it stored, the php file? Or on tpl?

Comment: i believe {$baseurl} < is also recognized by smarty engine. Is there a general location that is suppose to hold all these {$baseurl}, {$images}  @chandresh_cool

Comment: Ye basically this #menu variable is basically passed from .php extension file to .tpl file using view handlers. So you can access it in .tpl

Comment: Basically thi baseurl etc are been set from a common file which can be accessed by all files. In my case it was in Controller.php inside lib folder. You can also refer any such file which is common for all in your acse.

Answer (score 2):

`eq` is just an alternative of `==`

Please see http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if